# Peewee MemoryError binary data storage

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I'm trying to to store about 350MB of binary data to `peewee.BlobField` I'm getting a `MemoryError`. I have no issues with slightly smaller files ~250MB. How can I store 350MB? Memory error is not related to the OS memory. I have few GB of free memory.

This is how I am trying to store data:

```
Subproducts.create(cfg_id=config_id,
                   c=c,
                   mf=mf_data.getbuffer()
```

`type(mf_data)` is `<class '_io.BytesIO'>`

This is how my model looks like:

```
class Subproducts(BaseModel):

    cfg = peewee.ForeignKeyField(ConfigModel, related_name='cfg')
    c = peewee.TextField()
    mf = peewee.BlobField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('cfg', 'c'), True),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was 32bit Python. There are no issues when using 64bit python